# X,Y Position of points on circle with n segments

Tags: functions, trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I am trying to create the script.

Known things are:

- s: Number of segments
- sR: Segment distance from  centre (from 0 to 1(point on edge))

Important thing is start point and always go clockwise

What I need is some equation which I can place into loop and calculate `s` X and Y for each iteration

I am pretty bad at math but I did some tests and think sin function can help.

https://prnt.sc/haq1nn

https://prnt.sc/haq71w

Comment: Your description sounds like you want the coordinate of the vertices of a regular polygon with $s$ edges/vertices, and the distance from the center of that polygon to the vertices is $sR$. Also, what do you mean by "calculate $s$"? I understand "calculate $X$ and $Y$", but I'm not too sure about $s$.

Comment: Yes I need x,y of every s(polygon corner) and sR is radius of this polygon but its between 0 and 1